# How to sort Dynamically allocated array with bubble sort algorithm written in inline assembly?

Tags: inline-assembly

So i have an assignment where i have to sort dynamically allocated array with a bubble sort written as inline assembly function. Trouble is that my assembly function won't work with dynamically allocated array.

```
int *array;
array=new int[N];                //N=number of elements
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    //generate random numbers
}

        N--;
    __asm {
            outer_loop:
                    xor  edx, edx       
                    lea  esi, array

                        mov  ecx, N     



            inner_loop:
                    mov  eax, [esi]  
                    mov  ebx, [esi+4]

                    cmp  eax, ebx
                    jae  next_pair   

                    mov  [esi], ebx  
                    mov  [esi+4], eax

                    add  edx, 1      


            next_pair:
                    add  esi,4      
                    dec  ecx         
                    jnz  inner_loop  

                    test edx, edx    
                    jnz  outer_loop  
            }
for(int t=0;t<5;t++)
    {
        cout<<array[t]<<" ";           // it get's stuck here "Unhandled exception" 
    }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I am a NOOB and I'm kinda out of options so yea.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in masm32 because you should be using  Visual studio that uses masm syntax, and my compiler is the GCC,  your bubble sort don't work because lea esi, array replaces for mov esi, array maybe it work because I don't tested in VS, the fragment of code is in intel syntax and AT&T syntax is here

void BubbleSort(int *array, int n) {

```
n--;

__asm__ __volatile__(

    "outter_loop:\n"
                     ".intel_syntax noprefix\n" // use intel syntax 
                     "xor  edx,  edx\n"
                     ".att_syntax prefix\n"     //  back to at&t to get parameters
                     "movl %[p], %%esi\n"       //  mov esi, array
                     "movl %[n], %%ecx\n"       //  mov ecx, n     
                     ".intel_syntax noprefix\n"
     "inner_loop:\n"

                     "mov eax, [esi]\n"
                     "mov ebx, [esi+4]\n"
                     "cmp eax, ebx\n"
                     "jae next_pair\n"

                     "mov [esi], ebx\n"
                     "mov [esi+4], eax\n"
                     "mov edx, 1\n"

     "next_pair:\n" 

                     "add esi, 4\n"
                     "dec  ecx\n"
                     "jnz inner_loop\n"
                     "test edx, edx\n"
                     "jnz outter_loop\n"
                     ".att_syntax prefix\n" //  back to at&t again
                     :
                     :[p]"m"(array), [n]"m"(n)
                     : "%eax", "%ebx", "%ecx", "%edx", "%esi"); // clobbered registers
```

}

well this code fragment works perfectly since you wanted to makes in order from highest to lowest.